# Why are instance attributes of itemgetter not accessible?

Tags: python, operators

When I try to access `_items` attribute of a itemgetter,

```
from operator import itemgetter
itemgetter('name')._items
```

It throws

`AttributeError: 'operator.itemgetter' object has no attribute '_items'`

same with `attrgetter`

```
attrgetter('a')._attrs
```

gives

```
AttributeError: 'operator.attrgetter' object has no attribute '_attrs'
```

looking at the source of operator module:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/operator.py#L265-L294
they should be accessible.

Anyone knows whats going on here?

Comment: That's the fall-back Python implementations, you'll notice [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/51f1ae5ceb0673316c4e4b0175384e892e33cc6e/Lib/operator.py#L408) it tries to import from the [C extension module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Modules/_operator.c): `from _operator import *`

Comment: Oh, got it, thanks. Just curious, when would the import fail and python version is used?